# Div overlap when printing

Tags: html, css

When I print the following code, the Green footer overlaps the yellow container. I need that the Yellow breaks and goes to the next page when the Footer is encountered when printing.

HTML is as follows

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
            This is the container
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        This is the footer
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS is as follows

```
body{
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
}

.container{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1500px;

}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #21f50056 
}
```

Comment: Since the footer is position fixed, is it therefore taken out of the document flow, yet it is relative to the viewport. there's no relation between the two(footer and yellow div), as if they were in two separate documents, also `bottom:0` means no space between the bottom edge of the footer and the bottom edge of the viewport so it will be stuck to the edge of the viewport(the browser window meaning the first page) if you set top:100% it will do the same as bottom only using the top edge of the footer, your best bet is to set it's top to 1500px same as the height of the container

Comment: I need the footer to repeat on each page so the position has to be fixed. I basically need that the content that I put in the container should not get hidden by the footer. If only there was some way to specify the margin from bottom of page a print page...

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using javascript, before adding any element I check the height of the container. If the height exceeds the page height, insert a page break.